# WooCommerce "Product Categories List" widget not appearing to select from the available widgets' list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For some reason I am not able to choose the WooCommerce "Product Categories List" widget from the available widgets on my WordPress.

Here's an example of this widget:

[image]

Since the version `5.8.0` several widgets passed to be on the new "Legacy Widget" list — https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/29/block-based-widgets-editor-in-wordpress-5-8/

I am using the version `5.8.1` and I am not able to select it from this new "Legacy Widget" list.

I have another installation with the same version `5.8.1` and it shows up there the option "Product Categories List" from the list available on the "Legacy Widget".

Does anyone else had encounter this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the cause for this problem. Basically, WooCommerce is hiding the "Legacy Widgets" who are replaced by new "equivalent widgets".

Thanks to @7uc1f3r the right solution to this question is to remove this filter on your `functions.php` file, like this:

```php
remove_filter( 'widget_types_to_hide_from_legacy_widget_block', array( 'BlockTypesController', 'hide_legacy_widgets_with_block_equivalent' ) );
```

Comment: **NEVER edit core files!** When WC gets updated, it overwrites the installation with any new updates included in the release. If the core has been chopped up and modified beforehand, it’ll wipe out those changes. That means big sections of the installation will just stop working. Modifying the core can have all kinds of unintended consequences, like preventing updates from working correctly, further screwing up an installation. Even worse is the potential to introduce unintended security vulnerabilities. Messing with core files could easily introduce a hole allowing hackers to take over a site

Comment: Just use: `remove_filter( 'widget_types_to_hide_from_legacy_widget_block', array( 'BlockTypesController', 'hide_legacy_widgets_with_block_equivalent' ) );` instead. Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or active theme).